# Dynamically reference an import in Webpack

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Here's the issue:
I want to dynamically reference an image / file import depending on the prop passed. Say, select imageA if prop is "imageA" and similarly for imageB.

I am using `url-loader` to load image paths in webpack.

```
import imageA from "../imgs/A";
import imageB from "../imgs/B";

const component=({ imageName /* will be either "imageA" or "imageB" */ }) => 
   // Select either imageA or imageB 
   // depending on the imageName
    <img src={imageName} />
```

Can I do this without creating a object mapping of all images and using switch case to select the right import.

Comment: I am not sure about dynamic imports using Webpack 1, but I spotted the feature in Webpack 2 - https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7#dynamic-expressions
May be worth following the trail here, but I still can't imagine how the resolution would work without some sort of up front declaration of all the possible values.

Comment: Useful reading here too: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#dynamic-requires

Comment: Can you do this without creating a mapping? No. The name you give the imports is internal stuff. It'll be thrown away by your minifier too. A simple object map that points to the imported image will be fast and efficient. You can always do `images[imageName]` to get the value out of the object (or undefined if the key/imageName doesn't exist).